# Sillypage on overleaf

Tags: overleaf

Hello how can I subdue the error illustrated below when using sillypage package. [image]
Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{sillypage} \usepackage{blindtext} \begin{document} \pagenumbering{silly} \Blinddocument \end{document}
```

Comment: you would need to get the package from ctan and add to your project, or wait for overleaf to add texlive 2022.

Answer (score 9):

As of August 10, 2022, [TeX Live 2022 is now available on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-2022-now-available), so you can use `sillypage` out  of the box! Just a reminder:

- For an existing project, you have to manually switch to TeX Live 2022 for `sillypage` to be available. Thankfully, Overleaf makes it easy via the [Switch your TeX Live compiler](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-select-your-tex-live-compiler-version) feature.
- For a new project, it will automatically be based on TeX Live 2022, so no further action required.

Hope it helps!

Comment: it is important to note that "can" does not mean "should"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can we have it included in the kernel? `:)`

Comment: no ............

Comment: oh ............

Answer (score 6):

Of course the best option is indeed to download the package from CTAN, compile it and add it to your Overleaf project.

However, if you just want the silly page numbers then you can implement a poor man's version, i.e., a highly simplified version of the package. The basic idea of the package is to include a page from a pdf with silly walks to show as page number.

You can find the pdf (made by samcarter, license CC BY-SA 4.0) on http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sillypage/sillywalk-map.pdf, which you have to download and add to your Overleaf project. This document contains 12 pages, so after 12 pages you need to go back to page 1. This you can do with modulo, i.e., page counter mod 12.

A bit of housekeeping is needed: 12 mod 12 = 0, which is not a valid page number to include from sillywalk-map.pdf. To solve this you can add 1. However, then the first page becomes 2, therefore you should start at 0.

One way to implement the calculations is with the `intcalc` package, which offers `\intcalcMod` for modulo and `\intcalcInc` for adding 1.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{intcalc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% sillywalk-map.pdf by samcarter
% source: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sillypage
% license: CC BY-SA 4.0
\setcounter{page}{0}
\def\thepage{\includegraphics[page=\intcalcInc{\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{12}},height=0.8cm]{sillywalk-map}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```